# How can I get this timer for my progress bar?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently learning how to create progress bars but Ive run into a problem. I'm not sure how I can reference the running timer in my CraftCopperBar script for my update. Or if I have the wrong idea please correct me.

```
public IEnumerator CraftCopperBar()
{
    while (copper >= copperBarValue)
    {
        button.SetActive(false);
        copper -= copperBarValue;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f);
        copperBar += 1 * multiplier;

        if (copper < copperBarValue)
        {
            button.SetActive(true);
            break;
        }
    }

public void Update()
progressBar.fillAmount = (float)(x / 5f);
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to reference (that you don't know how to do)? e.g.: which variable(s)?

Comment: Im trying to reference the WaitForSeconds(5f) timer that is running so I can fill the x in progressBar.fillAmount = (float)(x / 5f);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade to auto continuous timer in `IEnumerator`. This is a good way to solve your problem, In the following code, you no longer need the Update event for fill progress.

```cs
public IEnumerator CraftCopperBar(float waitTime)
{
    while (copper >= copperBarValue)
    {
        copper -= copperBarValue;
        button.SetActive(false);

        var timer = 0f;
        while (timer <= waitTime)
        {
            timer += Time.deltaTime;

            progressBar.fillAmount = timer / waitTime;
            
            yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        }
        copperBar += 1 * multiplier;

        if (copper < copperBarValue)
        {
            button.SetActive(true);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Also put wait time in parentheses.

```cs
public void Start() => StartCoroutine(CraftCopperBar(5f));
```

---

### How to Stop Coroutine?

Also this is a way to stop coroutine.

```cs
public Coroutine craftCoroutine;
public void Start()
{
    craftCoroutine = StartCoroutine(CraftCopperBar(5f));
}
public void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S)) StopCoroutine(craftCoroutine);
}
```

Comment: Wow. This is exactly what I was looking for you are an absolute LEGEND. Thank you so much.

Comment: @CodingNewbie I'm glad to hear that. Thank you very much. My intention was to help solve your problem ;)

Comment: I have a question. This coroutine doesnt seem to stop when I use StopCoroutine(CraftCopperBar(5f)) but unity's StopAllCoroutines() seems to work. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: @CodingNewbie OPS, this requires a technique and of course two different ways. You must save Coroutine. If you have any questions, please email. Kian.tianxuan@gmail.com

Comment: @CodingNewbie I added how to save coroutine in the answer.

Comment: I've entered exactly that but it still seems to continue. Have I done something wrong?

Comment: @CodingNewbie Please send all your code. I re-checked the method is not a problem.